# Need help on PIVOT with NULL value

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have this data set, and wanted to do a pivot.

**Data**

```
Series_Name         Rec_Id  Series_Value    Point_Color
Hs avg CVD1 P1A     420     8810            NULL
Hs avg CVD1 P1B     420     8850.5          NULL
Hs avg CVD1 P2A     420     8793.5          R
Hs avg CVD1 P2B     420     8806.5          R
```

**Expected result.**

```
 Rec_Id Point_Color Hs avg CVD1 P1A     Hs avg CVD1 P1B     Hs avg CVD1 P2A     Hs avg CVD1 P2B
 420    R           8810                8850.5              8793.5              8806.5
```

But at this moment, from what I have try, this is the result I get, I guess it is the NULL and 'R' value on column Point_Color causing it. Please advice how to get the expected result?

**Current result I get**

```
Rec_Id  Point_Color Hs avg CVD1 P1A     Hs avg CVD1 P1B     Hs avg CVD1 P2A     Hs avg CVD1 P2B
420     NULL        8810                8850.5              NULL                NULL
420     R           NULL                NULL                8793.5              8806.5
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show the query you use.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query to get the desired result.

```
SELECT Rec_Id,
      SUM([Hs avg CVD1 P1A]) AS [Hs avg CVD1 P1A], 
      SUM([Hs avg CVD1 P1B]) AS [Hs avg CVD1 P1B], 
      SUM([Hs avg CVD1 P2A]) AS [Hs avg CVD1 P2A], 
      SUM([Hs avg CVD1 P2b]) AS [Hs avg CVD1 P2b], 
      MAX(Point_Color) AS Point_Color
FROm #Test 
PIVOT(SUM(Series_Value) FOR Series_Name IN (
                                            [Hs avg CVD1 P1A], 
                                            [Hs avg CVD1 P1B], 
                                            [Hs avg CVD1 P2A], 
                                            [Hs avg CVD1 P2b]
                                            )
    ) AS P 
GROUP BY Rec_Id
```

Answer (score 0):

**SAMPLE TABLE**

```
SELECT * INTO #TEMP
FROM
(
    SELECT 'Hs avg CVD1 P1A' Series_Name,      420 Rec_Id,     8810  Series_Value,           NULL Point_Color
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Hs avg CVD1 P1B',     420,     8850.5,          NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Hs avg CVD1 P2A',     420,     8793.5,          'R'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Hs avg CVD1 P2B',     420,     8806.5,          'R'
)TAB
```

Since you are grouping `Point_Color` in pivot, it will treat `NULL` and `R` separately. In order to avoid `NULL` and group with `R`, you need to replace `NULL` with `R` to get your expected result.

**(1) Pivot statically.**

```
SELECT Rec_Id, Point_Color,
MIN(CASE WHEN Series_Name='Hs avg CVD1 P1A' THEN  Series_Value END) [Hs avg CVD1 P1A],
MIN(CASE WHEN Series_Name='Hs avg CVD1 P1B' THEN  Series_Value END) [Hs avg CVD1 P1B],
MIN(CASE WHEN Series_Name='Hs avg CVD1 P2A' THEN  Series_Value END) [Hs avg CVD1 P2A],
MIN(CASE WHEN Series_Name='Hs avg CVD1 P2A' THEN  Series_Value END) [Hs avg CVD1 P2B]
FROM
(
    SELECT Rec_Id,ISNULL(Point_Color,'R') Point_Color,Series_Name,Series_Value  
    FROM #TEMP
)TAB
GROUP BY Rec_Id,Point_Color
```

**(2) Pivot dynamically**

If the values in `Series_Name` is unknown in advance, you can go with dynamic pivot.

Get columns for pivot.

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + ',[' + Series_Name + ']', '[' + Series_Name + ']')
               FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT Series_Name FROM #TEMP) PV 
               ORDER BY Series_Name
```

Now pivot it.

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = 'SELECT * FROM 
             (
                 SELECT Series_Name,Rec_Id,Series_Value ,ISNULL(Point_Color,''R'') Point_Color  
                 FROM #TEMP
             ) x
             PIVOT 
             (
                 MIN(Series_Value)
                 FOR Series_Name IN (' + @cols + ')
            ) p
            ORDER BY Rec_Id;' 

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

**RESULT**

[image]

Comment: Is this the result what u r expecting? @Ryan